# curious relation between orders of generators of a finite group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, and $g,h\in G$ be such that $G = \langle g,h\rangle = \langle g,hgh^{-1}\rangle$ - that is, $g,h$ generate $G$, and so does $g,hgh^{-1}$.

Let $n := |G|$, $r := |g|$, and $e := |ghg^{-1}h^{-1}|$ ("$|.|$" denotes "order")

I was doing some computations with covers of curves, and it seems that my computations give the following relation:
$$e \ge \frac{n}{2+n-\frac{2n}{r}}$$
The cleanest special case is if $r = 2$, in which case one gets $e\ge \frac{n}{2}$ (in which case we must have $e = \frac{n}{2}$ barring the trivial case when $G$ is cyclic, so that the commutator subgroup is cyclic of index 2)

Firstly, is this true? (I've checked it to be true for the smallest 10 or so finite simple groups, where it seems to hold).

If so, this is somewhat curious to me. Is this related to any known results?

Comment: Wait... if $e$ is the order of $[g,h]$, then you necessarily have $e\leq n/2$: the order cannot be equal to $n$, since then $G$ would be cyclic and $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$ would be trivial; and so must be a proper divisor of $n$, hence at most equal to $n/2$. Are you actually asserting that when $g$ is of order $2$, then the order $e$ of $[g,h]$ must be *equal* to $n/2$, and so that the commutator subgroup must be either of index $2$ or equal to all of $G$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes I suppose that is what I claim. Is that obviously wrong? The first example I checked was the case $G = D_{2k}$, where $g$ is a reflection, and $h$ is either a primitive rotation or another reflection which generates with $g$. In either case $g,hgh^{-1}$ generate $G$ iff $k$ is odd, and in that case $e$ is indeed equal to $k$, which is also the order of the commutator subgroup.

Comment: Seems like a strong condition, and ex nihilo I wouldn't expect it to be true; but the condition you have on the generators may be stronger than it seems at first glance...

Comment: If $G$ is cyclic, then it is generated by $g$ of order $2$, and so $n=r=2$ and $e=1$, so the equality would also hold when $G$ is cyclic if $r=2$.

Comment: I guess $|g|$ is supposed to mean the order of $g$?

Comment: @ycor yes sorry will clarify

Comment: For any real numbers, if $e,r \geq 3$ and $n > 0$, then $e \geq \frac{n}{2+n-\frac{2}{r}}$.

Comment: @ZachTeitler Oh crap you're right. I guess I should have noticed that, hah! I guess at least the $r = 2$ case is still mildly interesting. At least this sort of validates my computations.

Comment: When $r=2$, $g$ is an involution and so is $g^h$, so $G$ is generated by two involutions so must be a dihedral group.

Comment: There was a typo in my comment. Sorry. I meant: If $e,r \geq 3$ and $n>0$, then $e \geq \frac{n}{2+n-\frac{2n}{r}}$. And it also holds automatically if $e=2$ and $r \geq 4$. I guess the $r=2$ case, and maybe the $e=2,r=3$ case, could still be interesting!

Comment: Write $t=hgh^{-1}$. Then $G$ is generated by $t$ and $g$, which both have order $r$, and $gt^{-1}=ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$ has order $e$.
In particular, $G$ is a quotient of $\langle g,t \mid g^r, t^r, (gt^{-1})^e\rangle$. When $r=2$, this is a dihedral group of order $2r$. When $r=3$ and $e=2$, this is $A_4$.

Comment: For $A_5$ group, $n=60$, but there is no element of order $30$ there. The orders of elements are $2,3,4,5$. The standard generators are of order $2,3$, for example $(1,2)(3,4)$, $(1,3,5)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Denote $f=hgh^{-1}$.

1) If $r\geqslant 4$, then $n\geqslant 4$ and either $e=1$, $r=n$ or $e\geqslant 2>\frac{n}{2+n/2}\geqslant \frac{n}{2+n-2n/r}$.

2) If $r=3$, then either $e\geqslant 3\geqslant \frac{n}{2+n/3}=\frac{n}{2+n-2n/3}$ or $e=2$, then we have $f^3=g^3=1$, $(fg)^2=1$. It follows that the group generated by $f,g$ contains at most 12 elements, since it is a factor of the group $\langle f,g|f^3=g^3=1,(fg)^2=1\rangle=A_4$. But for $n\leqslant 12$ we have $e=2\geqslant \frac{n}{2+n/3}$.

3. $r=2$. Then $n$ does not exceed the order of the group generated by relations $f^2=g^2=1$, $(fg)^e=1$. This group contains at most $2e$ elements as desired. Indeed, all elements have the form either $(fg)^k$, or $(fg)^kf$, where $k=0,1,\dots,e-1$.